# process echo command output in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, echo, socat

I'm trying to extract `icy-title` information from mpv player and turn it into usable string with python.
I play file with `mpv http://hd.stream.frequence3.net/frequence3-256.mp3 --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket`
and then to gather song's title I use `echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "metadata"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket`
My question is how do I get this output returned to python script either variable or list? 
I've been googling for few hours and couldn't get it to do what I'm expecting..

Comment: Just start the command from Python and retrieve its output. You could also avoid the additional process by replicating the `socat` functionality.